# How can I associate bash command to Git Bash instead of WSL Bash?

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Git Bash and WSL Bash installed. Currently bash command is associated to WSL Bash. Can I link it to Git bash instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it myself after researching.

In PowerShell, you can associate bash command to Git Bash with

```
Set-Alias -Name bash -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe"
```

But it will only be effective for the PowerShell session you have run the command.

Comment: Any way to make this work in scripts as well? It seems to only work when using the command directly